# how can i know if a First order logic sentences is valid or unsatisfiable or neither?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, first-order-logic

i have trouble with understand this type of questions ,

i know how i can determine if the sentences is valid or unsatisfiable in Propositional logic , but in FOL i can't

for example , i have the following sentences in FOL :

```
1 = 2
```

the professor said this is neither valid nor unsatisfiable

but , i think it is always unsatisfiable , because 1 != 2 !!!

can someone explain to me how can i answer this type of question

thank you all

Comment: It depends on your axioms. Imagine that instead you had the sentence $a = b$ – that would be neither valid nor unsatisfiable. Unless your axioms state the contrary about 1 and 2, then there is no difference between the two statements.

Answer (score 2):

A formula is *valid* if **all** of the possible truth-assignments to its variables evaluate to true.

A formula is *satisfiable* if **at least one** of the truth-assignments to its variables evaluates to true.

The formula you gave is :

> $1 = 2$

Since this contains no variables, under any truth-assignment, the expression is $1 = 2$, which is false.

Neither of the above conditions have been met.

Therefore the formula is neither ***valid*** nor ***satisfiable***. Since it is not satisfiable, we can say that it is ***unsatisfiable***.

Comment: I'm not sure *permutations* is the correct word here.

Comment: Is that better @Yuval Filmus?

Comment: No, still not the right word. You can say that a sentence is valid if it is satisfied in all interpretations, or for all assignments of its variables.

Comment: Your statements contradict one another.  Permutation also works as it is a super set of the combinations.

Comment: Combinations implies choosing some unordered subset of a set, and permutations imply choosing an ordered permutation of a set. Truth-assignments is definitely the word you're looking for.

Comment: Wasn't OP asking for satisfiability in FOL? You can't really talk about plain truth assignments as though it were propositional logic.